# lxc(-net ?) problems when starting container on debian Buster

Tags: debian, lxc

I've (tried to) set things up to allow myself to have some unprivileged containers I can start (and then use) as needed.

Now I can create new containers with `lxc-create`, but when I try to start one, this happens

```
> lxc-start --name frisk-buster                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 ~
lxc-start: frisk-buster: lxccontainer.c: wait_on_daemonized_start: 842 Received container state "ABORTING" instead of "RUNNING"
lxc-start: frisk-buster: tools/lxc_start.c: main: 330 The container failed to start
lxc-start: frisk-buster: tools/lxc_start.c: main: 333 To get more details, run the container in foreground mode
lxc-start: frisk-buster: tools/lxc_start.c: main: 336 Additional information can be obtained by setting the --logfile and --logpriority options
> lxc-start --name frisk-buster -F
lxc-start: frisk-buster: network.c: lxc_create_network_unpriv_exec: 2178 lxc-user-nic failed to configure requested network: cmd/lxc_user_nic.c: 1296: main: Quota reached
                                                                                                                                                                          lxc-start: frisk-buster: start.c: lxc_spawn: 1777 Failed to create the configured network
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   lxc-start: frisk-buster: start.c: __lxc_start: 1951 Failed to spawn container "frisk-buster"
                                 lxc-start: frisk-buster: tools/lxc_start.c: main: 330 The container failed to start
lxc-start: frisk-buster: tools/lxc_start.c: main: 336 Additional information can be obtained by setting the --logfile and --logpriority options
```

(I have no clue why line breaks look like that, when I run the container in foreground mode, but it doesn't really matter)

The only thing I've found online when searching for that error is advice to edit `/etc/lxc/lxc-usernet` to contain "your-username veth lxcbr0 10", but on my system it already does (except that right now I've set the limit to 25 to verify that it wasn't the problem.

What can be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Quota reached" message was actually right. For some reason (Probably copy-paste from different sources, that did things differently even though I hadn't seen that), the configuration file for my container said to make an interface called *vir*br0, while the `lxc-usernet` configuration allowed me to create interfaces called *lxc*br. Changing *vir* to *lxc* in the container's config fixed things.